# How to receive dynamic length data from a message queue?

Tags: c++, malloc, message-queue

I have to send and receive dynamic data using a SysV message queue for a university project.

The length of the data is transmitted in a separate message, `size` is therefor already known.

And this is how I try to receive the data. I have to admit that I'm not a C++ specialist, especially when it comes to memory allocation.

```
struct {
    long mtype;
    char *mdata;
} msg;

msg.mdata = (char *)malloc(size * sizeof(char));

msgrcv(MSGQ_ID, &msg, size, MSG_ID, 0);
```

The problem seems to be the `malloc` call, but I don't know how to do this right.

**EDIT**

What I try is to have a some sort of *read* method in a OO wrapper around the message queues. I'd like to read the data in the message queue into a `char[]` or a `std::string`. What I have now looks (simplified) like this.

```
bool Wrapper::read(char *data, int length)
{
    struct Message {
        long mtype;
        std::string mdata;
    };

    Message msg;
    msg.mdata = std::string(size, '\0');

    if(msgrcv(MSGQ_ID, &msg, size, MSG_ID, 0) < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    memcpy(data, msg.mdata.c_str(), msg.mdata.size());

    return true;
}
```

All I get is segmentation faults or completely corrupt data (although this data sometimes contains what I want).

Comment: In C++, always use new.  Never use malloc.

Comment: You say "the problem seems to be the malloc call".  Why do you think this?  What errors/diagnostics are you getting?  Is this a run time error, or a compile time error?  More info is needed.

Comment: Sorry... I get segmentation faults.

Comment: I just looked up the API - this must be one of the worst designed APIs ever. That being the case, please ignore my answer, which I have deleted.

Comment: The new code you posted definitely won't work. There doesn't seem to be a good way of using msgrcv() in C++ without invoking undefined or implementation specific behaviour. With that proviso, William's approach is about the best you can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass a pointer to a structure that contains a `std::string` member to `msgrcv`, this violates the interface contract.

The second parameter passed to `msgrcv` needs to point to a buffer with sufficient space to store a 'plain' C struct of the form `struct { long mtype; char mdata[size]; };` where size is the third parameter to `msgrcv`.

Unfortunately, determining the size of this buffer might depend on `size` due to possible alignment issues but you have to assume that it doesn't on a system that provides this sort of interface. You can use the standard `offsetof` macro to help determine this size.

As a `vector` stores its components contiguously, once you know the size of the buffer, you can resize a `vector` of `char` and use this to hold the buffer. Using a `vector` relieves you of the obligation to `free` or `delete[]` a buffer manually.

You need to do something like this.

```
std::string RecvMessage()
{
    extern size_t size; // maximum size, should be a parameter??
    extern int MSGQ_ID; // message queue id, should be a parameter??
    extern long MSG_ID; // message type, should be a parameter??

    // ugly struct hack required by msgrcv
    struct RawMessage {
        long mtype;
        char mdata[1];
    };

    size_t data_offset = offsetof(RawMessage, mdata);

    // Allocate a buffer of the correct size for message
    std::vector<char> msgbuf(size + data_offset);

    ssize_t bytes_read;

    // Read raw message
    if((bytes_read = msgrcv(MSGQ_ID, &msgbuf[0], size, MSG_ID, 0)) < 0)
    {
        throw MsgRecvFailedException();
    }

    // a string encapsulates the data and the size, why not just return one
    return std::string(msgbuf.begin() + data_offset, msgbuf.begin() + data_offset + bytes_read);
}
```

To go the other way, you just have to pack the data into a `struct` hack compatible data array as required by the msgsnd interface. As others have pointer out, it's not a good interface, but glossing over the implementation defined behaviour and alignment concerns, something like this should work.

e.g.

```
void SendMessage(const std::string& data)
{
    extern int MSGQ_ID; // message queue id, should be a parameter??
    extern long MSG_ID; // message type, should be a parameter??

    // ugly struct hack required by msgsnd
    struct RawMessage {
        long mtype;
        char mdata[1];
    };

    size_t data_offset = offsetof(RawMessage, mdata);

    // Allocate a buffer of the required size for message
    std::vector<char> msgbuf(data.size() + data_offset);

    long mtype = MSG_ID;
    const char* mtypeptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&mtype);

    std::copy(mtypeptr, mtypeptr + sizeof mtype, &msgbuf[0]);
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), &msgbuf[data_offset]);

    int result = msgsnd(MSGQ_ID, &msgbuf[0], msgbuf.size(), 0);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        throw MsgSendFailedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This look great, exactly what I wanted to do. But it doesn't work either. My problem seems to be that sending data suffers from the same problems.

Would you mind posting a similar method for sending a std::string? I tried doing it myself, but this didn't work.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help.
I already found a working implementation for the send method.
To my surprise your receive method didn't work as expected. Although the data is send correctly, I get corrupted data inside the vector<char>.
When using my malloc implementation (or calloc or new char[]) from above (striked out) I get the correct data in msg.mdata and I can put it into a std::string. But as soon as I try to return the string I get a pretty cryptic SIGSEGV with no obvious source.

Too sad the project is nearing it's deadline - seems like I'll never find the right way.

Comment: Why not post your send method, then we have a chance of helping. What do you mean by corrupted data? the vector of char is just a buffer so it's not going to contain only the contents of the sent message. the extracted string *should* be correct but without being able to see the data it's impossible to tell. What does the stack trace look like when the SIGSEGV is raised?

Comment: Is it safe to pass the address of msgbuf[0] to msgrcv()? Is there any guarantee that the implementation of std::vector<char> has the data in a contiguous array starting at msgbuff[0] ?

Comment: @Dave Rigby: Yes, it is. A vector is guaranteed to be stored continguously and a vector of `char` can be treaded the same as an array of `char` when needed. i.e. `&v[0] + n` is identicall `&v[n]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [an example for SyS](http://www.ecst.csuchico.edu/~beej/guide/ipc/mq.html). I hope it will help.

The way you are using malloc seems to be correct but you should be very careful when making memory allocations for IPC. You should check how the other process is managing memory (byte alignment, size, platform...)

In your code, What is the purpose of the mtype? Does the size you receive takes this mtype into account? Or is it only the size of mdata?

Update: Is mtype part of the message?

If so:

msgsize = size * sizeof(char) + sizeof(long)

pmsg = malloc(msgsize);

msgrcv(MSGQ_ID, pmsg, msgsize, MSQ_ID, 0);

if not

msg.data = (char *)malloc(size * sizeof(char));

msgrcv(MSGQ_ID, msg.data, size, MSQ_ID, 0);

The mtype is alocated on the stack while the data is allocated on the heap. If the msgreceive makes a kind of memcpy on the given pointer, it will cause some troubles.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be freely mixing C and C++, so I'll do the same.
Note that you probably ought to write the function entirely in C, put it in its own translation unit and then call it from C++, but this should solve your immediate problem.
It seems that the root of your confusion is arguably poor design of the API of msgrcv.  You cannot have the data member of the msg struct be a pointer or a reference or anything other than a raw chunk of memory--msgrcv is going to put the data directly into the structure.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


/* Caller must ensure that data points to at least length chars */
bool read_msg( char *data, int length )
{
    bool status = false;
    struct msg {
        long mtype;
        char data[ 1 ];
    } *m = (struct msg *)malloc( length + offsetof( struct msg, data ));

    if( m != NULL ) {
        if( msgrcv( MSGQ_ID, m, length, MSQ_ID, 0 ) == length ) {
            memcpy( data, m->data, length );
            status = true;
        }
    }

    free( m );

    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Root cause**
The cause of your segementation error is that memcpy tries to copy a message greater then the size of your struct. Your struct has only room for a long (4 bytes) and a std:string. A string can be a variable size, but only when used as string (and it will automatically allocate memory for this and maintain a pointer). 
The std:string variable will look like

```
struct {
  unsigned int stringlength;
  char *pString;
}
```

Your code copies into msg, which in this (simplified) example is only 8 bytes long. And you overwrite the pointer with data, which is later interpreted as a memory location.

**Solution**
A solution is to allocate a memory block large enough to hold both the header (mtype) and the message of *size* bytes. Since it is only temporary space, I'd suggest to use a stack variable for this. So

```
 struct msg {
        long mtype;
        char data[ size ];
    }
```

I suggest to replace *size* with something more unique and meaningfull if it is a global constant. Please note that *size* is expressed in bytes; if you need to send a std::string of *size* characters you'll need to increase the array length with at least sizeof(std::string)+1 (for the structure overhead and the \0 character); better a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for segmentation faults or corrupted data is that you're using an improper message structure for `msgrcv()` and `msgsnd()` functions. These functions require the following structure to be used:

```
struct msgbuf {
    long mtype;     /* message type, must be > 0 */
    char mtext[1];  /* message data */
};
```

But your `Message` structure contains an `std::string` which allocates memory on the heap, but the `msgbuf` structure expects a memory region starting at `mtext[0]`. The `mtext` member is not a pointer, but a char array inside the structure. As the size is unknown, the array is declared as a 1 sized array, but actually the caller shall provide a larger buffer. This technique is also used in some Windows APIs.

For being able to receive messages, you need a buffer

```
static const unsigned int BufferSize = 256;
char* buffer = new char[ sizeof(long) + BufferSize ];
msgbuf* msg = reinterpret_cast< msgbuf* >( buffer );
```

Then this `msg` can be passed to `msgrcv()`. And don't forget to `delete[]` the buffer.

Also be aware that the text received in the buffer is not null terminated, unless the 0 character is explicitly written when sending the message. Such non-null terminated text can be used either constructing an `std::string` from it - e.g. `std::string( msg->mtext, len )` or reserving in the buffer one byte for the 0 and write it after receiving the message at the length returned by `msgrcv()`

Instead of plain char arrays, you could use std::vector which guarantees that the items will be stored in a continuous memory range. The following code can be used in a message receiving loop, which automatically increases the buffer size if the message does not fit into.

```
static const unsigned int InitialBufferSize = 32;
std::vector<char> buffer( InitialBufferSize );
msgbuf* msg = new (&buffer[0]) msgbuf();
// reserve space in the vector for the mtype member of msgbuf structure
std::vector<char>::size_type available = buffer.size() - sizeof(long);

for(;;)
{
    const ssize_t count = ::msgrcv( MSGQ_ID, msg, available, 0, 0 );
    if( -1 == count )
    {
        if( E2BIG == errno )
        {
            buffer.resize( buffer.size() * 2 );
            msg = new (&buffer[0]) msgbuf();
            available = buffer.size() - sizeof(long);
            continue;
        }
        perror( "Failed to read message from queue" );
        break;
    }

    // handle the received message
    ...
}
```