# Peek into Sys V Message Queue in C linux

Tags: c, linux, ipc, message-queue, peek

Is there any way to peek into a message queue in C without removing the element?

I want one process to send message(msg_len + message text) to another process.

I first want to read msg_len and then malloc space=msg_len for it in the second process in a character array and then read the message text.

There is no way for partial reading of messages in sysV message queue.

At most it truncates the message but I want remaining part also but after malloc.

So I was thinking to first peek the msg_len and malloc and then reading the whole message.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Possibly answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181816/how-to-receive-dynamic-length-data-from-a-message-queue

Comment: no @Phillip . there only size (here, msglen) is received and remaining msg is truncated. However I do not want that. I then want to read the rest of the message. still Thanks :)

Comment: There is no peeking; there are no partial reads.  It's an all-or-none operation.  Why do think you need to do this because the chances are pretty good you don't.